# OMEdit simulation flags “-override” and “-overrideFile” usage

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

Can someone share simple examples on usage of simulation flags “-override” and “-overrideFile” in Openmodelica's OMEdit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a simple mos-script showing how to use override and overrideFile

```
loadString("model M Real r(start=1.0) = der(r); end M;");
simulate(M);
val(r, 0.5);
simulate(M, simflags="-override r=2.0");
val(r, 0.5);
writeFile("a.txt", "r=4.0\n");
simulate(M, simflags="-overrideFile=a.txt");
val(r, 0.5);
```

Returns r at time=0.5 as 1.65, 3.30, 6.59 (showing that the start-value is overridden; you can also override some parameters depending on how it was defined and used in the model).

Comment: Thanks for quick answer and the sample. I am not successful in using simulation flags “–override” or “–overrideFile” in OMEdit. Does the simulation flags work in OMEdit? Does the override flags in OMShell do the same job as re-simulate the model by entering the values from the variables browser in OMEdit?

Comment: I believe OMEdit internally uses overrideFile, which will replace the overrides that you try to define. I'm not at a computer to check the source code at the moment though.

Comment: When you enter the values in Variables browser then OMEdit writes them to the model_init.xml file and then re-simulate the model using that values. What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: @AdeelAsghar Simulated the sample model (`model M Real r(start=1.0) = der(r); end M;`) in OMEdit. I tied to override the start value of “r” using the simulation flag “`–override r=2.0`” in OMEDit. It does not work. If I change the “r” value from the variables browser and re-simulates, it works fine. 
Does simulation flags “`–override`” and “`-overideFile`” works in OMEdit?
In the sample model, I just want to override the start value of “r” in OMEdit using simulation flags “`–override`” and “`-overideFile`”. Is this possible?

Comment: No you can't use them directly. OMEdit uses them internally so only way for you is to change the values via Variables Browser.